# How to remove strings like July 1, 2019

Tags: python, regex, date, datetime

I have a big string and I want to remove all date-string substrings from it. By constraint, date-strings  all follow the format:

Month string day, year (Ex: September 1, 2018)

Suppose my string is:

`bad_s = "It was a fine day. September 1, 2018 and I had a lot of laughs August 2, 2017"`

I want to return 
`good_s = "It was a fine day. and I had a lot of laughs"`

Is there an easy way to do so in Python?

Here is what I tried:

```
reg_ex = """/[\'January\'\,\ \'February\'\,\ \'March\'\,\ \'April\'\,\ \'May\'\,\ \'June\'\,\ \'July\'\,\ \'August\'\,\ \'September\'\,\ \'October\'\,\ \'November\'\,\ \'December\'](?:\^\(\[1\-9\]\|\[12\]\\d\|3\[0\-q\]\)\$)/"""
replaced = re.sub(reg_ex, bad_s, "")
```

However, this does not replace what I want. I end up with `bad_s` still.

EDIT: If it makes it easier for anyone, here's a list of 12 months so you don't have to write them:
`months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']`

Comment: What have you tried so far and what didnt work with it?

Comment: create a regex, use findall to get a list of instances that match the pattern, loop over the list and replace in the string with ''

Comment: I have tried that with re.sub, but could not get the query to work.

Comment: Is there other number than the date numbers ?

Comment: would this work: `\w+\s+\d{1,2}\,\s+\d{4}`?

Comment: an ideal solution would be to use `datetime.strptime()` to find the dates & then use `re.sub` to replace it with a null `""` in `bad_s`

Answer (score 3):

Like this?

```
(january|february|march|april|may|june|july|august|september|octorber|november|december) ([1-9]|[1-2]\d|3[01]), \d{4}
```

Just don't forget the `/i` flag or whatever the Python equivalent is.

Do note that this does not care how many days a month has so `February 31, 2017` is going to match and it doesn't care about leap years either. This regex is a matcher not a validator.

If you want it to be more generic and completely ignore date validation then this would work:

```
(january|february|march|april|may|june|july|august|september|octorber|november|december) \d+, \d+
```

https://regex101.com/r/zVbb0v/5

Comment: I didn't know about this site, great!

Comment: @CeliusStingher Learn something new every day! There are several of them available. You can search for "regex visualizer" for more such as https://regexr.com/ and https://jex.im/regulex/ but I've found regex101 to be the most comprehensive especially since it provides a code generator for many popular languages.

Comment: Matches `february 31, 2009`

Comment: @sln Yes, I mentioned that scenario in my answer. This regex serves as a matcher, not a validator. Even if you expand the regex to account properly for days of the month you will still be left with a dead-end for leap-years.

Comment: It's not just leap years, your regex also matches  `september 31, 2019` This is simple stuff to do.

Comment: @sln I assumed that was a given since February 31 is not a valid date regardless of leap year. Once again, my regex is not a validator.

Comment: Feel free to update my regex to match only valid days of a given month.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this:

import re

```
bad_s = 'It was a fine day. September 20, 2018 and I had a lot of laughs August 2, 2017'
regex = '([^\s]+ ([1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\, ([12]\d{3}))'

for x in re.findall(regex, bad_s):
    bad_s = bad_s.replace(x[0], '')

print(bad_s)
```

Result:

```
"It was a fine day.  and I had a lot of laughs"
```

Comment: Matches `february 31, 2009`